# Is icon for votes cast in activity tab misleading?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

As i see now in activity tab in user's profile the icon for votes cast is an upper arrow ▲.

I believe this is misleading because the upper arrow represents the upvotes. So someone can think that all votes are upvotes. I believe the icon should be changed to something like this:

▲
▼

so both upvotes and downvotes be represented.

Comment: I think it's understandable, specially when you can hover on it and see good description. Also, I don't expect any icon to cover all possible things, for example ☏ can represent communication method, not necessarily an old phone :) Having the suggested icon will break the symmetric and won't look good (at least for me).