# Votes cast has upvote-like symbol and is confusing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, voting

[image]

I've cast `1,152` votes, fine. But the icon beside it in my honest opinion  *seems* to indicate that they are *upvotes*.

It's like I've upvoted 1152 posts, when I've clearly not. I've predominantly downvoted if you ask me.
Can something more generic be used to indicate votes? Maybe a stat like icon or both up and down arrow?

Comment: I lol'd. Check out [Eric Lippert's profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=topactivity).

Comment: I wonder who received that one upvote

Comment: Jon Skeet. Jon Skeet is always the answer.

Comment: @AmitJoki, unfortunately the upvote was a random [mistake](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270746/high-downvote-to-upvote-ratio-not-serial-downvoting#comment92368_270750).

Comment: Good on him for being an all-rounded contributor to the community...

Comment: I thought at one point it was the up/down arrow pair used on the privileges page (or maybe someone suggested that in the feedback question on the Big Meta).

Comment: The `tooltip` says _Total number of up and down votes cast_. But your point seems legit..

Comment: "_But the icon beside it in my honest opinion seems to indicate that they are upvotes._". I my humble opinion they seems that they are triangles.

Comment: @FlorinGhita and in my humble opinion, the triangle pointed upwards in SE sites mean an upvote. Context matters.

Comment: But, but, but... I don't vote up or down. I vote to close!

Comment: @AmitJoki sure, it was a joke

Comment: @CodeCaster a small stat like icon might be used. And as far as a downvote and upvote, I'd expect the icon designers to distinguish between an upvote and a downvote and presumably, there would be a visible space between those(as is in the actual upvote and downvote buttons), which well, might clear any ambiguity that might crop up.

Comment: @FlorinGhita geez, okay! I might not be the best pun-pickers :p

Comment: @CodeCaster - this **`∨∧`** is not like a diamond ;)

Comment: @Cliff yeah I wasn't so certain about how serious OP was, so I tried to make a joke.

Comment: Oh, I was entirely sure that was what that icon meant (upvotes) until this post. I hadn't even reflected over it before now.

Comment: Looks like an oversight on our end. I'm putting a [tag:status-review] on this while I confirm that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is icon for votes cast in activity tab misleading?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294683/is-icon-for-votes-cast-in-activity-tab-misleading)

Comment: @SheshankS. Yes, but this one has an official response (the [status-review] tag) and the other one doesn't, so I voted to close the other one as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 32):

Just inspect the element and change the span class to `icon icon-up-down`
Problem solved (until you reload the page)

Comment: Yeah! This clears ambiguity. It's from privileges section I guess, but I'm not sure. FTW!

Comment: Unfortunately that icon is wider and makes the text not line up :(

Comment: We might need to turn this into a browser extension, before the problem gets out of hand.

Answer (score 19):

#### Stackoverflow Profile Vote Icon Changer UserScript

Until this very important feature request is made [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), well...

Am I doing this right?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stackoverflow Profile Vote Icon Changer
// @version      0.1
// @description  This script changes the votes icon to up AND down. Very important.
// @author       @misterManSam
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js
// ==/UserScript==

$('.impact-card .icon').css({'width':'18px'});
$('.impact-card .icon-vote-cast').switchClass('icon-vote-cast','icon-up-down').css({'width':'23px','margin-left':'-5px'});
```

It feels better now:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've added a slightly tweaked version of your fix into my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script. And yes, I've credited both you and AgeDeO in the code and release notes.

Answer (score 6):

This portion of the user profile page has since been changed, and now looks like this:

[image: screnshot of "votes cast" section of user profile page, with explanatory tooltip]